# Corrplot: positioning colorlegend so that it is guaranteed to be in a particular location relative to the plot?

Tags: r, r-corrplot

HI I'm using the corrplot package and would like to draw the legend manually.  The code below works fine, however in a markdown or for plots with a different dataset finding the correct xlim and ylim position is difficult.  Is there a way to always ensure that the legend is always position exactly at a location relative to the overall plot regardless of size or dataset?  thanks!

```
test <- matrix(data = rnorm(400), nrow=20, ncol=20)
    corrplot(test,  is.cor = FALSE )
    colorlegend(xlim=c(28,30), ylim=c(10,15), scalebluered, c(-2,1), 
                align="l", vertical=TRUE, addlabels=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could base the coordinates of xlim and ylim on the size of your matrix. for example:

```
nrow<-20
ncol<-20

test <- matrix(data = rnorm(400), nrow=nrow, ncol=ncol)
corrplot(test,  is.cor = FALSE )

x<-nrow/2                                                                                                                                                      
y<-ncol/4*3

colorlegend(xlim=c(x,y), ylim=c(x,y),labels=c("label"), colbar=c(1),
            align=c("l"), vertical=TRUE, addlabels=TRUE)
```

Comment: I changed your colorlegend function a bit because 'scalebluered' was not found.